# If I export my jar via eclipse, the images don't load when ran. I am rather new to loading images

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, assets, image-loading

I have looked at a number of tutorials, but nothing seems to work.  I don't understand what I need to change to get the images to load when run from an exported jar.  When I run the jar I get a blank `JFrame`.

Here is some relevant code.  I can add more if need be:

Main:

```
package dev.darokrithia.packer;

import java.io.InputStream;

public class Main {

    // Class.getResourceAsStream

    public static InputStream packer = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("nested");
    public static InputStream tiles = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("nested");
    public static InputStream enemy = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("nested");
    public static InputStream ally = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("nested");
    public static InputStream dead = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("nested");
    public static InputStream bigBad = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("nested");
    public static InputStream projectiles = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("nested");
    public static InputStream hack = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("nested");
    public static InputStream win = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("nested");
    public static InputStream lose = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("nested");

    public static void main (String args[]){

        packer = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/images/packerSpriteSheet.png");
        tiles = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/images/tileSpriteSheet.png");
        enemy = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/images/enemySpriteSheet.png");
        ally = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/images/hackedSpriteSheet.png");
        dead = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/images/deadEnemySpriteSheet.png");
        bigBad = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/images/evilComputer.png");
        projectiles = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/images/projectileSpriteSheet.png");
        hack = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/images/hackText.png");
        win = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/images/winScreen.png");
        lose = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/images/loseScreen.png");

        Game game = new Game("Packer",512,512);
        game.start();
    }

}
```

Image Handler:

```
package dev.darokrithia.packer.graphics;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ImageHandler {

    public static BufferedImage loadImage(InputStream s){
        try {
            return ImageIO.read(s);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error, image not found");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Assets:

```
package dev.darokrithia.packer.graphics;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import dev.darokrithia.packer.Main;

public class Assets {
    //Packer's Animations and graphics
    public static SpriteSheetHandler packerSpriteSheet;
    public static BufferedImage packerDownStatic;
    public static BufferedImage packerRightStatic;
    public static BufferedImage packerUpStatic;
    public static BufferedImage packerLeftStatic;

    public static BufferedImage packerDownStaticShoot;
    public static BufferedImage packerRightStaticShoot;
    public static BufferedImage packerUpStaticShoot;
    public static BufferedImage packerLeftStaticShoot;

    public static BufferedImage[] packerDownMove = new BufferedImage[4];
    public static BufferedImage[] packerRightMove = new BufferedImage[4];
    public static BufferedImage[] packerUpMove = new BufferedImage[4];
    public static BufferedImage[] packerLeftMove = new BufferedImage[4];

    public static BufferedImage[] packerDownShoot = new BufferedImage[4];
    public static BufferedImage[] packerRightShoot = new BufferedImage[4];
    public static BufferedImage[] packerUpShoot = new BufferedImage[4];
    public static BufferedImage[] packerLeftShoot = new BufferedImage[4];


    //Enemies' Animations and graphics
    public static SpriteSheetHandler enemySpriteSheet;
    public static BufferedImage enemyStatic;

    public static BufferedImage enemyDownStaticShoot;
    public static BufferedImage enemyRightStaticShoot;
    public static BufferedImage enemyUpStaticShoot;
    public static BufferedImage enemyLeftStaticShoot;

    public static BufferedImage[] enemyDownMove = new BufferedImage[4];
    public static BufferedImage[] enemyRightMove = new BufferedImage[4];
    public static BufferedImage[] enemyUpMove = new BufferedImage[4];
    public static BufferedImage[] enemyLeftMove = new BufferedImage[4];

    public static BufferedImage[] enemyDownShoot = new BufferedImage[4];
    public static BufferedImage[] enemyRightShoot = new BufferedImage[4];
    public static BufferedImage[] penemyUpShoot = new BufferedImage[4];
    public static BufferedImage[] enemyLeftShoot = new BufferedImage[4];

    public static SpriteSheetHandler alliedSpriteSheet;
    public static BufferedImage alliedStatic;

    public static BufferedImage alliedDownStaticShoot;
    public static BufferedImage alliedRightStaticShoot;
    public static BufferedImage alliedUpStaticShoot;
    public static BufferedImage alliedLeftStaticShoot;

    public static BufferedImage[] alliedDownMove = new BufferedImage[4];
    public static BufferedImage[] alliedRightMove = new BufferedImage[4];
    public static BufferedImage[] alliedUpMove = new BufferedImage[4];
    public static BufferedImage[] alliedLeftMove = new BufferedImage[4];

    public static BufferedImage[] alliedDownShoot = new BufferedImage[4];
    public static BufferedImage[] alliedRightShoot = new BufferedImage[4];
    public static BufferedImage[] alliedUpShoot = new BufferedImage[4];
    public static BufferedImage[] alliedLeftShoot = new BufferedImage[4];


    public static SpriteSheetHandler deadEnemySpriteSheet;
    public static BufferedImage deadEnemy;

    public static SpriteSheetHandler finalEnemySpriteSheet;
    public static BufferedImage finalEnemy;

    //Projectile graphics
    public static SpriteSheetHandler bulletSpriteSheet;
    public static BufferedImage[] packerBulletRight = new BufferedImage[2];
    public static BufferedImage[] packerBulletLeft = new BufferedImage[2];
    public static BufferedImage[] packerBulletUp = new BufferedImage[2];
    public static BufferedImage[] packerBulletDown = new BufferedImage[2];

    public static BufferedImage[] evilBulletRight = new BufferedImage[2];
    public static BufferedImage[] evilBulletLeft = new BufferedImage[2];
    public static BufferedImage[] evilBulletUp = new BufferedImage[2];
    public static BufferedImage[] evilBulletDown = new BufferedImage[2];

    //Tile Animations and graphics
    public static SpriteSheetHandler tileSpriteSheet;
    public static BufferedImage grassTile;
    public static BufferedImage tileTile;
    public static BufferedImage carpetTile;
    public static BufferedImage waterTile;
    public static BufferedImage brickTile;

    //Hack mode
    public static SpriteSheetHandler hackText;

    public static SpriteSheetHandler winText;
    public static SpriteSheetHandler loseText;

    public static BufferedImage win;
    public static BufferedImage lose;

    public static void init(){
        packerSpriteSheet = new SpriteSheetHandler(Main.packer);
        packerDownStatic = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(0, 0, 32, 32);
        packerRightStatic = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(32, 0, 32, 32);
        packerUpStatic = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(64, 0, 32, 32);
        packerLeftStatic = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(96, 0, 32, 32);

        packerDownStaticShoot = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(128, 0, 32, 32);
        packerRightStaticShoot = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(160, 0, 32, 32);
        packerUpStaticShoot = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(192, 0, 32, 32);
        packerLeftStaticShoot = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(224, 0, 32, 32);

        packerDownMove[0] = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(0, 32, 32, 32);
        packerRightMove[0] = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(32, 32, 32, 32);
        packerUpMove[0] = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(64, 32, 32, 32);
        packerLeftMove[0] = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(96, 32, 32, 32);
        packerDownMove[1] = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(0, 0, 32, 32);
        packerRightMove[1] = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(32, 0, 32, 32);
        packerUpMove[1] = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(64, 0, 32, 32);
        packerLeftMove[1] = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(96, 0, 32, 32);
        packerDownMove[2] = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(0, 64, 32, 32);
        packerRightMove[2] = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(32, 64, 32, 32);
        packerUpMove[2] = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(64, 64, 32, 32);
        packerLeftMove[2] = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(96, 64, 32, 32);
        packerDownMove[3] = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(0, 96, 32, 32);
        packerRightMove[3] = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(32, 96, 32, 32);
        packerUpMove[3] = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(64, 96, 32, 32);
        packerLeftMove[3] = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(96, 96, 32, 32);

        packerDownShoot[0] = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(128, 32, 32, 32);
        packerRightShoot[0] = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(160, 32, 32, 32);
        packerUpShoot[0] = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(192, 32, 32, 32);
        packerLeftShoot[0] = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(224, 32, 32, 32);
        packerDownShoot[1] = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(128, 0, 32, 32);
        packerRightShoot[1] = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(160, 0, 32, 32);
        packerUpShoot[1] = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(192, 0, 32, 32);
        packerLeftShoot[1] = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(224, 0, 32, 32);
        packerDownShoot[2] = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(128, 64, 32, 32);
        packerRightShoot[2] = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(160, 64, 32, 32);
        packerUpShoot[2] = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(192, 64, 32, 32);
        packerLeftShoot[2] = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(224, 64, 32, 32);
        packerDownShoot[3] = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(128, 96, 32, 32);
        packerRightShoot[3] = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(160, 96, 32, 32);
        packerUpShoot[3] = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(192, 96, 32, 32);
        packerLeftShoot[3] = packerSpriteSheet.selectImage(224, 96, 32, 32);


        enemySpriteSheet = new SpriteSheetHandler(Main.enemy);
        enemyStatic = enemySpriteSheet.selectImage(0, 0, 32, 32);

        enemyDownStaticShoot = enemySpriteSheet.selectImage(0, 0, 32, 32);

        enemyDownMove[0] = enemySpriteSheet.selectImage(0, 32, 32, 32);
        enemyRightMove[0] = enemySpriteSheet.selectImage(32, 32, 32, 32);
        enemyUpMove[0] = enemySpriteSheet.selectImage(64, 32, 32, 32);
        enemyLeftMove[0] = enemySpriteSheet.selectImage(96, 32, 32, 32);
        enemyDownMove[1] = enemySpriteSheet.selectImage(0, 0, 32, 32);
        enemyRightMove[1] = enemySpriteSheet.selectImage(32, 0, 32, 32);
        enemyUpMove[1] = enemySpriteSheet.selectImage(64, 0, 32, 32);
        enemyLeftMove[1] = enemySpriteSheet.selectImage(96, 0, 32, 32);
        enemyDownMove[2] = enemySpriteSheet.selectImage(0, 64, 32, 32);
        enemyRightMove[2] = enemySpriteSheet.selectImage(32, 64, 32, 32);
        enemyUpMove[2] = enemySpriteSheet.selectImage(64, 64, 32, 32);
        enemyLeftMove[2] = enemySpriteSheet.selectImage(96, 64, 32, 32);
        enemyDownMove[3] = enemySpriteSheet.selectImage(0, 96, 32, 32);
        enemyRightMove[3] = enemySpriteSheet.selectImage(32, 96, 32, 32);
        enemyUpMove[3] = enemySpriteSheet.selectImage(64, 96, 32, 32);
        enemyLeftMove[3] = enemySpriteSheet.selectImage(96, 96, 32, 32);

        alliedSpriteSheet = new SpriteSheetHandler(Main.ally);
        alliedStatic = alliedSpriteSheet.selectImage(0, 0, 32, 32);

        alliedDownStaticShoot = alliedSpriteSheet.selectImage(0, 0, 32, 32);

        alliedDownMove[0] = alliedSpriteSheet.selectImage(0, 32, 32, 32);
        alliedRightMove[0] = alliedSpriteSheet.selectImage(32, 32, 32, 32);
        alliedUpMove[0] = alliedSpriteSheet.selectImage(64, 32, 32, 32);
        alliedLeftMove[0] = alliedSpriteSheet.selectImage(96, 32, 32, 32);
        alliedDownMove[1] = alliedSpriteSheet.selectImage(0, 0, 32, 32);
        alliedRightMove[1] = alliedSpriteSheet.selectImage(32, 0, 32, 32);
        alliedUpMove[1] = alliedSpriteSheet.selectImage(64, 0, 32, 32);
        alliedLeftMove[1] = alliedSpriteSheet.selectImage(96, 0, 32, 32);
        alliedDownMove[2] = alliedSpriteSheet.selectImage(0, 64, 32, 32);
        alliedRightMove[2] = alliedSpriteSheet.selectImage(32, 64, 32, 32);
        alliedUpMove[2] = alliedSpriteSheet.selectImage(64, 64, 32, 32);
        alliedLeftMove[2] = alliedSpriteSheet.selectImage(96, 64, 32, 32);
        alliedDownMove[3] = alliedSpriteSheet.selectImage(0, 96, 32, 32);
        alliedRightMove[3] = alliedSpriteSheet.selectImage(32, 96, 32, 32);
        alliedUpMove[3] = alliedSpriteSheet.selectImage(64, 96, 32, 32);
        alliedLeftMove[3] = alliedSpriteSheet.selectImage(96, 96, 32, 32);

        deadEnemySpriteSheet = new SpriteSheetHandler(Main.dead);
        deadEnemy = deadEnemySpriteSheet.selectImage(0, 0, 32, 32);
        finalEnemySpriteSheet = new SpriteSheetHandler(Main.bigBad);
        finalEnemy = finalEnemySpriteSheet.selectImage(0, 0, 128, 128);

        bulletSpriteSheet = new SpriteSheetHandler(Main.projectiles);
        packerBulletRight[0] = bulletSpriteSheet.selectImage(0, 0, 16, 16);
        packerBulletRight[1] = bulletSpriteSheet.selectImage(16, 0, 16, 16);
        packerBulletLeft[0] = bulletSpriteSheet.selectImage(0, 16, 16, 16);
        packerBulletLeft[1] = bulletSpriteSheet.selectImage(16, 16, 16, 16);
        packerBulletUp[0] = bulletSpriteSheet.selectImage(0, 32, 16, 16);
        packerBulletUp[1] = bulletSpriteSheet.selectImage(16, 32, 16, 16);
        packerBulletDown[0] = bulletSpriteSheet.selectImage(0, 48, 16, 16);
        packerBulletDown[1] = bulletSpriteSheet.selectImage(16, 48, 16, 16);

        evilBulletRight[0] = bulletSpriteSheet.selectImage(32, 0, 16, 16);
        evilBulletRight[1] = bulletSpriteSheet.selectImage(48, 0, 16, 16);
        evilBulletLeft[0] = bulletSpriteSheet.selectImage(32, 16, 16, 16);
        evilBulletLeft[1] = bulletSpriteSheet.selectImage(48, 16, 16, 16);
        evilBulletUp[0] = bulletSpriteSheet.selectImage(32, 32, 16, 16);
        evilBulletUp[1] = bulletSpriteSheet.selectImage(48, 32, 16, 16);
        evilBulletDown[0] = bulletSpriteSheet.selectImage(32, 48, 16, 16);
        evilBulletDown[1] = bulletSpriteSheet.selectImage(48, 48, 16, 16);

        tileSpriteSheet = new SpriteSheetHandler(Main.tiles);
        grassTile = tileSpriteSheet.selectImage(0, 0, 32, 32);
        tileTile = tileSpriteSheet.selectImage(32, 0, 32, 32);
        carpetTile = tileSpriteSheet.selectImage(64, 0, 32, 32);
        waterTile = tileSpriteSheet.selectImage(96, 0, 32, 32);
        brickTile = tileSpriteSheet.selectImage(0, 32, 32, 32);

        hackText = new SpriteSheetHandler(Main.hack);

        winText = new SpriteSheetHandler(Main.win);
        win = winText.selectImage(0, 0, 512, 512);
        loseText = new SpriteSheetHandler(Main.lose);
        lose = loseText.selectImage(0, 0, 512, 512);
    }

}
```

Sprite Sheet Handler

```
package dev.darokrithia.packer.graphics;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class SpriteSheetHandler {

    private BufferedImage sheet;

    public SpriteSheetHandler(BufferedImage s){
        this.sheet = s;
    }
    public SpriteSheetHandler(InputStream s){
        this.sheet = ImageHandler.loadImage(s);
    }

    public BufferedImage selectImage(int x, int y, int w, int h){
        return this.sheet.getSubimage(x, y, w, h);
    }

}
```

Comment: So they're not ending up in the .jar file at all? Can you show where they start from and where they should end up, but aren't?

Comment: I assume (from what I have read) that they aren't showing up.  What happens when I run the game from the IDE is I get a perfectly functioning game.  What happens when I export it is I get just a blank / grey screen.

Comment: Details matter. Don't just assume things. If you're saying you need to get the images in your jar, make sure they're not already in there somewhere.

Comment: I just checked.  It would appear that they are in the jar, and I have edited my post.  Sorry about that.  Im a rookie.   Still, the images are not loading / the screen is blank.

Comment: OK, but again, where are they in the jar? Where are the classes?

Comment: They are in the top folder.  My classes are in the /dev/darokrithia/packer folders like they are in my workspace.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the images to the META-INF folder of my.jar

Comment: How would I go about doing that.  I tried viewing the files in the runnable jar and found the folder, but doing so only made a standard folder with the jar's content inside.